# How do I call log?

Tags: apache-pig

I got this error:

> Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.LOG
>   as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast

From this code:

```
> describe A;
A: {p: long,k: chararray,count: double}
> foreach (group A by p) generate SUM(A.count * LOG(A.count));
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose LOG works on a double, not on a bag of doubles. In your context you are giving it a bag, just as in SUM(A.count), but SUM is supposed to work with a bag.
Try to prepare you data before bag aggregations, something like:

```
computed = foreach A generate p, (count * LOG(count)) as multiplied;
summed = foreach (group computed by p) generate SUM(multiplied);
```